# sharing data between a cronjob and pod

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc, kubernetes-cronjob

Right now I have a cronjob that downloads data and I want to share it to another container that does the processing for the data as new ones are uploaded. I wanted to know if there was a way without any external services to share this data between the cronjob pod and my main pod?

I've tried creating a persistent volume and persistent volume claim to share the data but when the cronjob downloads the data it doesn't appear in the other pod even though the volume is mounted.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: download
spec:

  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  suspend: false 

  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:

      template:
        spec:
          volumes:
            - name: downloaded-data-claim
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: downloaded-data-claim

#container and image is here where it downloads
```

```
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: downloaded-data
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  claimRef:
    name: downloaded-data-claim
    namespace: default
  hostPath:
    path: "/tmp/"
```

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: downloaded-data-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  volumeName: downloaded-data
```

and then the pod mounts the volume

```
      volumes:
        - name: downloaded-data-claim 
          presistentVolumeClaim: 
            claimName: downloaded-data-claim
        - name: output
          emptyDir: {}

      containers:

        - name: "rand"
          image: <filler>
          imagePullPolicy: <filler>
          volumeMounts:
            - name: downloaded-data-claim 
              mountPath: /input
            - name: output  
              mountPath: /output  
          resources:
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created **CronJob** in right namespace - where your pod and pv are.
Take notice if you have access to directory where you want your data to be stored.

Actually I don't think there is other possiblity than using external services. 
Most useful are nfs volumes. But there are based on services and external nfs servers.
**NFS** stands for Network File System – it's a shared filesystem that can be accessed over the network.
The NFS must already exist – Kubernetes doesn't run the NFS, pods in just access it.